# NGINX Filter Location (wp-login.php) and Country

Tags: wordpress, nginx, filter

I have a section in my `http` block that sets country code based on CIDR blocks, like so:

```
geo $ip_country {
  default zz;
  include /www/conf/_country_ip_ranges.list;
}
```

The file `_country_ip_ranges.list` looks like this:

```
194.42.216.0/24 us;
195.42.132.0/23 us;
195.66.102.0/24 us;
(and so on)
```

I also have This in my `server` block:

```
location wp\-login\.php$ {
     if ($ip_country != us) {
        return 444;
     }
}
```

It correctly blocks access to wp-config.php from non-us addresses, but it also breaks php: when I access `wp-login.php` from a legitimate ip, it downloads the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The `location` block is missing any statements necessary to execute a PHP file. You probably have a `location ~ \.php$` block, and many of the same statements will need to be copied across to this `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for how `nginx` processes a request.

Comment: Thanks! In order to reduce duplicate code I broke the fastcgi stuff into an include and now I have two locations, one for secure stuff and one for all else.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard Smith's comment helped me get this sorted out.  I now have two location blocks, one for security-sensitive stuff that is restricted to host country and one for everything else:

```
# PHP : Secure WordPress Locations Limited To Host Country
location ~* (?:wp-login|admin\-ajax)\.php$ {
   if ($ip_country !~ us) {
     return 444;
   }
    include /path/to/example.com.php.inc;
}
# PHP: All Other PHP Locations
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /path/to/example.com.php.inc;
}
```

And I broke the fast-cgi directives into a separate file (`/path/to/example.com.php.inc`) for inclusion in both blocks in order to reduce duplicated lines.